# Autenticação de usuario Firebase

Tags: firebase

Utilizo o recurso de autenticação de email e senha do firebase, porem queria obter mais info do usuario como um telefone. Tem como fazer isto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que utilizar isto juntamente com o Firebase Database. Os dados do Auth não tem como inserir chaves customizadas.

Crie uma chamada para o banco de dados, e ao logar o usuario, acrescente as informações extras dele dentro de uma referencia no banco.